# Skip a commit and in Git

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

In my project one of the commits introduced a bug which I cannot locate. I want to ignore everything in it and continue from other commits.

**Commit1**: Works fine.

**Commit2**: Does not work. Introduced a bug.

**Commit3**: Does not work due to error on commit 2.

My question is how do I checkout commit 3 without changes made in commit 2?

Comment: You can revert commit 2.

Comment: But I would lose changes in commit if I do that, no?

Comment: @TheCook - No, you would not.  (Or to be clearer: you would not lose changes other than those you just said you don't want; and even those would still be viewable in history.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **interactive rebase to remove the `commit2` from commit history**. Detail steps as below (assume the 3 commits are on `master` branch):

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Then there will show interactive window. Input `i` and change the there commits as:

```
pick <commit1 sha-1> commit1 message
drop <commit2 sha-1> commit2 message
pick <commit3 sha-1> commit3 message
```

Then enter <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and input `:wq`.

Now `commit2` is removes and you will find `commit3`’s change is based on `commit1`.

Answer (score 3):

Like most of operations in Git, you can do it with several methods :

- Revert the wrong commit

  ```
  git revert <commit2>
  ```
- If this wrong commit hasn't been pushed to remote server (otherwise you better revert and push right away to fix it! =), and you want to keep your work somewhere and fix it later, you also could create a new local branch, cherrypick the correct commit and continue your work

  ```
  git checkout -b "myNewBranch" <commit1>
  git cherry-pick <commit3>
  ```
- if you have more than one commit to cherry-pick, rebase is more convenient

  ```
  ###create your branch but do not check it out yet.
  git branch "myNewBranch" <commit1> 
  git rebase <commit2> --onto "myNewBranch"
  ```

  this will take all commits starting from commit2(excluded) and apply them all one by one on your new branch.

If you're not comfortable with git command line and use rather gui, you can easily do it with gitk. This will work for simple operation such as reverts and cherrypicks.

One last advice, when starting with Git : 
You might do things wrong and mess up your workspace, you can always get back to a previous situation, as soon it has been versionned in a commit, using :

```
git reflog
//locate your commit and copy the sha key
git reset --hard mykey
```

Knowing this, don't hesitate when playing with the commands, as long as you don't push, you're safe ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this is unpushed history, you can use `git rebase --onto commit1 commit2 commit3` to remove commit2 from the history. If this is already published history, you should just revert the changes from commit2 with `git revert commit2`. Or if you only want to have it temporarily locally, you can checkout commit3 and then do `git revert commit2 -n` which also undoes the changes but does not create a commit.